# Why can't I use bg-red, bg-yellow in bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Classes like bg-primary, bg-seconadry work well.

But bg-red, bg-yellow don't work.

I checked at the compiled scss file. There were red, yellow, green in root.

I'm really curious.

And how do you activate them?

Comment: Because those aren't included in Bootstrap? Did you read [there documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/colors/) about colors?

Comment: @0stone0 When I posted this question, I didn't quite understand Bootstrap's compilation process. Thanks..!

Answer (score 4):

I guess you are refering to `bg-danger` for the red and `bg-warning` for the yellow.

Doc: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/colors/#background-color